# How to split a filename list in 5GB sets?

Tags: files, sed, awk, filenames

I have a pretty big list of files which I like to group in smaller list of 5GB each for further processing.

The file list is in the following form: "size" (from `du`) "tab" "absolute path", like this (I obfuscate the file names for privacy of the owner):

```
$ cat unix_StackExchange_question.txt 
543732  1.txt
543736  2.txt
543736  3.txt
543736  4.txt
543740  5.txt
543740  6.txt
543740  7.txt
543744  8.txt
543748  9.txt
543748  10.txt
543752  11.txt
543760  12.txt
543768  13.txt
543772  14.txt
543780  15.txt
543780  16.txt
543784  17.txt
543784  18.txt
543796  19.txt
543860  20.txt
546068  21.txt
546384  22.txt
548576  23.txt
549600  24.txt
549624  25.txt
549660  26.txt
549680  27.txt
549700  28.txt
549704  29.txt
549712  30.txt
549712  31.txt
549716  32.txt
549716  33.txt
549716  34.txt
549720  35.txt
549720  36.txt
549720  37.txt
549724  38.txt
549732  39.txt
549736  40.txt
549740  41.txt
549740  42.txt
549744  43.txt
549744  44.txt
549744  45.txt
549748  46.txt
549748  47.txt
549752  48.txt
549752  49.txt
549752  50.txt
549756  51.txt
549760  52.txt
549760  53.txt
549764  54.txt
549764  55.txt
549772  56.txt
549772  57.txt
549812  58.txt
549828  59.txt
550676  60.txt
550900  61.txt
553036  62.txt
556656  63.txt
557020  64.txt
563208  65.txt
569180  66.txt
569228  67.txt
569248  68.txt
569248  69.txt
569248  70.txt
569252  71.txt
569252  72.txt
569256  73.txt
569256  74.txt
569260  75.txt
569260  76.txt
569260  77.txt
569260  78.txt
569264  79.txt
569268  80.txt
569268  81.txt
569272  82.txt
569272  83.txt
569272  84.txt
569276  85.txt
569280  86.txt
569284  87.txt
569284  88.txt
569284  89.txt
569288  90.txt
569288  91.txt
569288  92.txt
569288  93.txt
569288  94.txt
569292  95.txt
569292  96.txt
569296  97.txt
569300  98.txt
569332  99.txt
569356  100.txt
569508  101.txt
576092  102.txt
577420  103.txt
584208  104.txt
587428  105.txt
680280  106.txt
680292  107.txt
682412  108.txt
682424  109.txt
689768  110.txt
689784  111.txt
690116  112.txt
690124  113.txt
690132  114.txt
690136  115.txt
690140  116.txt
690156  117.txt
690188  118.txt
690188  119.txt
690188  120.txt
690188  121.txt
690188  122.txt
690188  123.txt
690188  124.txt
690188  125.txt
690188  126.txt
690188  127.txt
690188  128.txt
690188  129.txt
690188  130.txt
690188  131.txt
690188  132.txt
690188  133.txt
690188  134.txt
690188  135.txt
690188  136.txt
690188  137.txt
690188  138.txt
690188  139.txt
690188  140.txt
690192  141.txt
690192  142.txt
690192  143.txt
690192  144.txt
690200  145.txt
690200  146.txt
690200  147.txt
690200  148.txt
690200  149.txt
690200  150.txt
690200  151.txt
690200  152.txt
690200  153.txt
690200  154.txt
690200  155.txt
690200  156.txt
690204  157.txt
690204  158.txt
690204  159.txt
690204  160.txt
690204  161.txt
690204  162.txt
690204  163.txt
690204  164.txt
690204  165.txt
690204  166.txt
690204  167.txt
690204  168.txt
690204  169.txt
690204  170.txt
690208  171.txt
690272  172.txt
690288  173.txt
690348  174.txt
690364  175.txt
690400  176.txt
690412  177.txt
696052  178.txt
697400  179.txt
697416  180.txt
697436  181.txt
697452  182.txt
699616  183.txt
700284  184.txt
700952  185.txt
700968  186.txt
702124  187.txt
702656  188.txt
704088  189.txt
704712  190.txt
704800  191.txt
706052  192.txt
706156  193.txt
706184  194.txt
706564  195.txt
706660  196.txt
706672  197.txt
706676  198.txt
706692  199.txt
706708  200.txt
706720  201.txt
706716  202.txt
706720  203.txt
706724  204.txt
706720  205.txt
706724  206.txt
706724  207.txt
706724  208.txt
706720  209.txt
706724  210.txt
706724  211.txt
706724  212.txt
706724  213.txt
706724  214.txt
706724  215.txt
706720  216.txt
706728  217.txt
706728  218.txt
706724  219.txt
706732  220.txt
706780  221.txt
706888  222.txt
706896  223.txt
707404  224.txt
708716  225.txt
708812  226.txt
709376  227.txt
711440  228.txt
711516  229.txt
713376  230.txt
713412  231.txt
714332  232.txt
716332  233.txt
718600  234.txt
732196  235.txt
737300  236.txt
737300  237.txt
743436  238.txt
743440  239.txt
743444  240.txt
747304  241.txt
748636  242.txt
748640  243.txt
748640  244.txt
748648  245.txt
748644  246.txt
748648  247.txt
748648  248.txt
755276  249.txt
755948  250.txt
761264  251.txt
761268  252.txt
782544  253.txt
787724  254.txt
795236  255.txt
801968  256.txt
801980  257.txt
801992  258.txt
801996  259.txt
801996  260.txt
802000  261.txt
802004  262.txt
802004  263.txt
802004  264.txt
802012  265.txt
802016  266.txt
802028  267.txt
802032  268.txt
802032  269.txt
802032  270.txt
802040  271.txt
802044  272.txt
802044  273.txt
802048  274.txt
802052  275.txt
802060  276.txt
802060  277.txt
802064  278.txt
802068  279.txt
802072  280.txt
802076  281.txt
802080  282.txt
802084  283.txt
802084  284.txt
802084  285.txt
802096  286.txt
802100  287.txt
802132  288.txt
802136  289.txt
802204  290.txt
802288  291.txt
803828  292.txt
804116  293.txt
808492  294.txt
813204  295.txt
826780  296.txt
829888  297.txt
831328  298.txt
831616  299.txt
832740  300.txt
832940  301.txt
833180  302.txt
833796  303.txt
833832  304.txt
834040  305.txt
834276  306.txt
834284  307.txt
834384  308.txt
834420  309.txt
834448  310.txt
834452  311.txt
834456  312.txt
834460  313.txt
834452  314.txt
834456  315.txt
834456  316.txt
834460  317.txt
834464  318.txt
834460  319.txt
834456  320.txt
834460  321.txt
834460  322.txt
834460  323.txt
834456  324.txt
834460  325.txt
834468  326.txt
834460  327.txt
834456  328.txt
834464  329.txt
834468  330.txt
834468  331.txt
834476  332.txt
834468  333.txt
834528  334.txt
834632  335.txt
834748  336.txt
834864  337.txt
835744  338.txt
836008  339.txt
836124  340.txt
837464  341.txt
837488  342.txt
838640  343.txt
838840  344.txt
842068  345.txt
908696  346.txt
908744  347.txt
908744  348.txt
916972  349.txt
917092  350.txt
917096  351.txt
917100  352.txt
917116  353.txt
917116  354.txt
917120  355.txt
917120  356.txt
917124  357.txt
917124  358.txt
917132  359.txt
922580  360.txt
922580  361.txt
923056  362.txt
923056  363.txt
924040  364.txt
925392  365.txt
925448  366.txt
925448  367.txt
937824  368.txt
950020  369.txt
950032  370.txt
954788  371.txt
954804  372.txt
955920  373.txt
959628  374.txt
963432  375.txt
963448  376.txt
964024  377.txt
964040  378.txt
964040  379.txt
964056  380.txt
964064  381.txt
964080  382.txt
964096  383.txt
964100  384.txt
964100  385.txt
964100  386.txt
964100  387.txt
964100  388.txt
964100  389.txt
964100  390.txt
964100  391.txt
964100  392.txt
964100  393.txt
964100  394.txt
964100  395.txt
964100  396.txt
964100  397.txt
964100  398.txt
964100  399.txt
964100  400.txt
964104  401.txt
964104  402.txt
964104  403.txt
964104  404.txt
964108  405.txt
964108  406.txt
964108  407.txt
964108  408.txt
964112  409.txt
964112  410.txt
964112  411.txt
964116  412.txt
964116  413.txt
964116  414.txt
964116  415.txt
964116  416.txt
964116  417.txt
964116  418.txt
964116  419.txt
964116  420.txt
964116  421.txt
964116  422.txt
964116  423.txt
964116  424.txt
964116  425.txt
964116  426.txt
964116  427.txt
964116  428.txt
964116  429.txt
964116  430.txt
964120  431.txt
964120  432.txt
964120  433.txt
964124  434.txt
964124  435.txt
964128  436.txt
964172  437.txt
964188  438.txt
964192  439.txt
964204  440.txt
964296  441.txt
964312  442.txt
972764  443.txt
972780  444.txt
976292  445.txt
976304  446.txt
979696  447.txt
979712  448.txt
988492  449.txt
1057628 450.txt
1090748 451.txt
1092992 452.txt
1098340 453.txt
1099496 454.txt
1100484 455.txt
1100528 456.txt
1100724 457.txt
1101532 458.txt
1111008 459.txt
1111016 460.txt
1111040 461.txt
1111052 462.txt
1111052 463.txt
1111056 464.txt
1111064 465.txt
1111072 466.txt
1111080 467.txt
1111084 468.txt
1111092 469.txt
1111100 470.txt
1111100 471.txt
1111100 472.txt
1111108 473.txt
1111120 474.txt
1111124 475.txt
1111132 476.txt
1111136 477.txt
1111136 478.txt
1111140 479.txt
1111160 480.txt
1111168 481.txt
1111168 482.txt
1111180 483.txt
1111184 484.txt
1111192 485.txt
1111236 486.txt
1111256 487.txt
1111344 488.txt
1116348 489.txt
1120988 490.txt
1137784 491.txt
1137784 492.txt
1138120 493.txt
1138120 494.txt
1138380 495.txt
1138380 496.txt
1204392 497.txt
1488592 498.txt
1757076 499.txt
```

BTW: those are just the biggest 500th files.

Is there a easy way to split this list in lists with files that sum up to approximately 5GB?

**Edit:** Wanted output for a possible solution

```
file1:
    2500000  478.txt
    2345872  400.txt
    134325   300.txt
file2:
    2134356  123.txt
    2857439  4325.txt
file
```

Comment: What is the information gain of showing 499 entries instead of one?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I almost replaced most of the lines with a `...` mark. But it might be useful for someone for testing, so better more info than less ;)

Comment: Can't write a full answer but you can run a `find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec du -k {} \;` then use `awk` to column count `$1`, appending the contents of each line's `$2` to an awk variable and just tell it to spit out each grouped together once the total gets to GB. You should probably check before appending, whether the final total will be over you 5GB limit else print the variable, reset it immediately and make the current `$2` the value. That'll give you a list of files that when grouped together are 5GB.

Comment: Considering that at least three people (including me) have misunderstood your question you should finally do what is general rule anyway: Provide the wanted output.

Comment: @HaukeLaging done, sorry for the imprecision on the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a solution to the [bin-packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). So far as we know, there isn't a way to do it both optimally and quickly (but we don't know there isn't one, either; its an open question).

But you can get close. One utility to do it is called [datapacker](https://github.com/jgoerzen/datapacker/wiki). Haven't used that one; found it by searching. I'm sure there are more.

Personally, I use one I wrote myself. (Note that these will all output the list of files that go into each bin; you can easily use `cat` to put them together in one text file.) The comment refers to `bfpp` which is another program I wrote, which finds the optimal solution as long as you only have a few (like, under 10) files:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# Sane bin packer. Attempts to finds a way to arrange a set of items
# into the fewest bins. Uses first-fit decreasing, which will get within
# 11⁄9⋅OPT + 6⁄9 (where OPT is the optimal number of discs, as found by
# bfpp). Unlike bfpp, this program will finish quickly.
#
# Also, this program features many more non-ASCII characters than bfpp.
# This is probably its most important feature.

use strict;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dump qw(pp);
use File::Next;
use List::Util qw(sum);
use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote);
use Carp qw(confess croak carp);

sub usage($) {
    say STDERR "Usage: $0 bin-size-megabytes file1 file2 ...";
    exit shift;
}

sub parse_command_line() {
    usage(1) if @ARGV < 3;
    usage(0) if $ARGV[0] =~ /^--?[h?]/;

    my $size = shift @ARGV;

    given ($size) {
        when (/^dvd5?$/) {
            $size = 4011;
        }
        when (/^dvd9$/) {
            $size = 7291;
        }
        when (/^bd(-r)?1?$/) {
            $size = 21360;
        }
        when (/^bd(-r)?2$/) {
            $size = 42720;
        }
        when (/^\d+$/) {
            # do nothing, already number
        }
        default {
            say STDERR "ERROR: Size must be number or known size constant (dvd, dvd9, bd, bd2)";
            usage(1);
        }
    }

    return {
        bin_size => $size * 1024 * 1024,
        items    => get_item_info(@ARGV),
    };
}

sub get_item_info {
    my %items;
    my ($in_group, $group_no) = (0, 0);
    foreach my $item (@_) {
        if ('(' eq $item ) {
            $in_group and confess "Nested groups not supported";
            $in_group = 1;
            ++$group_no;
            next;
        } elsif (')' eq $item) {
            $in_group or croak "Can't close a group when none open";
            $in_group = 0;
            next;
        }

        my $key;
        $in_group and $key = "!!__GROUP${group_no}__!!";

        if (-f $item) {
            defined $key or ($key = $item) =~ s/\..{2,4}$//;
            push @{$items{$key}{members}}, $item;
            $items{$key}{size} += -s _;
        } elsif (-d $item) {
            $key //= $item;
            my $files = File::Next::files($item);
            while (defined(my $file = $files->())) {
                push @{$items{$key}{members}}, $file;
                $items{$key}{size} += -s $file;
            }
        } else {
            confess "Not sure how to handle $item (weird type or doesn't exist)"
        }
    }

    $in_group and carp "WARNING: Group wasn't closed";

    return \%items;
}

sub check_sanity($) {
    my $info = shift;
    my $_;

    my $binsize = $info->{bin_size};
    my @dontfit = grep $info->{items}{$_}{size} > $binsize,
        keys %{$info->{items}};

    if (@dontfit) {
        say "\nWARNING! WARNING! WARNING! WARNING!";
        say "The following items are larger than the bin size:";
        say pp(\@dontfit);
        say "This is going to lead to some funny results.\n";
        say "WARNING! WARNING! WARNING! WARNING!\n";
    }

    return $info;
}

sub approximate_best {
    my $info = shift;

    my @sorted
        = sort { $info->{items}{$::b}{size} <=> $info->{items}{$::a}{size} }
        keys %{$info->{items}};

    my @bins;

FILE: foreach my $file (@sorted) {
        my $size = $info->{items}{$file}{size};
    BIN: foreach my $bin (@bins) {
            next BIN unless $bin->{remaining} >= $size;
            push @{$bin->{contents}}, $file;
            $bin->{remaining} -= $size;
            next FILE;
        }
        # didn't find a bin, open a new one
        push @bins,
            {
            remaining => $info->{bin_size} - $size,
            contents  => [$file],
            };
    }

    $info->{bins} = \@bins;

    return $info;
}

sub print_bins($) {
    my $info = shift;
    my $_;

    my $bins = $info->{bins};

    #<<< [Hide this mess from PerlTidy]
    use locale;
    my @bins_full = map { # for each disk
        [ sort( # sort each disk's fileset
            map { # for each fileset
                @{$info->{items}{$_}{members}}
            } @{$_->{contents}}
        ) ];
    } @$bins;
    #>>>
    for (my $d = 0; $d < @bins_full; ++$d) {
        print <<DISC
DISC #@{[$d + 1]}:   (@{[ int($bins->[$d]{remaining}/1024/1024) ]} MiB empty)
   @{[ join(qq{\n   }, @{$bins_full[$d]}) ]}

DISC
    }

    say "As space-separated, escaped values (for shell):";
    for (my $d = 0; $d < @bins_full; ++$d) {
        say $d+1, q{: }, shell_quote @{$bins_full[$d]};
    }

    return undef;
}

# believe it or not, the below is code.
print_bins approximate_best check_sanity parse_command_line;
```

Comment: I liked the bin-packing problem reading :) Thanks!

Comment: To me that doesn't sound like the bin-packing problem.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Especially from OP's edit, I it looks like it. OP wants to pack multiple files of varying sizes (the items) into single text files of a fixed maximum size (the bins).

Comment: @derobert Yes but there is no optimization involved. And without optimization there is no problem, is it?

Comment: @HaukeLaging correct, if you don't need to do optimal, there is a trivial solution (put one item in each bin). I interpreted OP's "sum up to approximately 5GB" as a request to get as close as possible w/o going over, i.e., optimization.

Comment: I didn't knew the bin-packing problem until this question, it surely looks like I need the same thing. @HaukeLaging Why do you say there is no optimization?

Comment: @RSFalcon7 I say that for the simple reason that (a) you don't mention that with a single word in your question and (b) none of the other answeres does anything of that kind and you did not make a single remark about that. Only your example output gives a hint in that direction.

Comment: @HaukeLaging the request to _"sum up to approximately 5GB"_ seems to imply optimization. Nonetheless, a good and interesting answer. Why debate?

Comment: @derobert since this endup being a relevant part of my thesis, I like to reference this answer in the thesis, should I add your username or do you prefer your real name (which I could not find it)?

Comment: @RSFalcon7 I thought my real name is in my profile, guess I'll have to check that. It's Anthony DeRobertis.

Comment: Thanks! It might not be public in the profile

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Using bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
groupsize=0
groupcnt=0
cat unix_StackExchange_question.txt | while read fsize fname
do
        [ "$groupsize" == "0" ] && echo "Group : GROUP_$groupcnt"
        echo -en "\t $fname\n"
        ((groupsize+=$fsize))
        #cp $fname GROUP_$groupcnt
        if [ "$groupsize" -gt "5000000" ]
        then
            ((groupcnt++))
            groupsize=0
        fi
done
```

Comment: It seems to me that not just me but you, too, have misunderstood the question. But technically: Why should one read a line with `read` and `echo` it to `awk` for separating the elements by whitespace instead of ` | read fsize fname`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging good idea ! but still don't solve the problem of filenames containing spaces. here i correct it.

Comment: @Slyx I don't think I have any filename with whitespaces

Comment: Check `man 1 split` and look for `-C, --line-bytes=SIZE` option and explanation.

Comment: @yeti You made the same mistake like me. That's not the result the OP wants.

Comment: @RSFalcon7 : May someone else having filenames containing spaces needs the same thing and find this post on google :-)

Comment: @Slyx It would even work with whitespace names. As long as there is no whitespace at the beginning or the end of the file name.

Comment: Hit shappens!   :-\

Comment: @yeti you misunderstood the question. `split` can't do the work.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, You're right. I edited to include your good idea !

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v sizelimit=5000000 -v outputfilename=shorter_list \
'BEGIN {target=outputfilename ".0000"}; '\
'{sum+=$1; '\
'if(sum>sizelimit) { file_index++; target=outputfilename "." sprintf("%04d",file_index); sum=$1;}; '\
'print $0 >target}' file
```

should do what you want. You have to adapt the size limit, though. I used a smaller value for testing (which might be useful for your testing, too).

Answer (score 3):

This should work with `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

accumulated_size=0
file_counter=0
out_file=file_0000

while read size name; do
  if [ "$accumulated_size" -gt 5368709120 ]; then
    (( file_counter += 1 ))
    out_file=$(printf 'file_%04d' "$file_counter")
    echo -n >"out_file"
    accumulated_size=0
  fi

  echo "$size $name" >>"$out_file"
  (( accumulated_size += size ))
done <unix_StackExchange_question.txt
```

A new file will be started for the first line that takes the accumulated size over 5GiB. So each file will contain sizes totalling just over 5GiB (unless the last file is very large).

#### Update

This should really be done with an `awk` script - the following is the equivalent in `awk`:

```
awk -v out_file=file_0000 '{
    if(accumulated_size > 5368709120){
      file_counter += 1
      out_file=sprintf("file_%04d", file_counter)
      accumulated_size=0
    }
  
    print >out_file
    accumulated_size+=$1
  }' unix_StackExchange_question.txt
```

Comment: +1 for `printf 'file_%04d'`

Comment: You count wrong. `accumulated_size=0` is wrong.

Comment: @HaukeLaging how come?

Comment: You write the line to the next file. Thus the size covered by the next file is not 0 but the size you just added.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, yes, I have moved the accumulation to the end of the loop. That should fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In lovely, understandable Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open('unix_StackExchange_question.txt') as f:
    files = f.read()
files = files.split('\n')

group = list()
group_size = 0
n = 0
for f in files:
    pair = f.split()
    if not pair:
        break
    size = int(pair[0])
    name = pair[1]
    group_size += size
    group.append(f)
    # assume the files are in ascending order as per the op's question
    if group_size + size >= 5000000:
        n += 1
        group_size = 0
        print 'file %s:\n\t' % n +'\n\t'.join(x for x in group) 
        group = list()
```

Just save as `5GBfiles.py` and `chmod +x 5GBfiles.py` and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

This one should do but it is slow ( 1m18s for 500 entries)

```
#!/bin/bash

#reformatting the initial file to remove tab

SRC=`cat file.txt | expand`

outputs_dir="outputs"

if [ ! -d "$outputs_dir" ];then
  mkdir "$outputs_dir"
else
 echo "$outputs_dir exist"
 #rm "$outputs_dir"/*
fi

#init file outputs array with 2 files first one is in case files is bigger than 5GB

foutputs_array=( "$outputs_dir"/leftover.txt "$outputs_dir"/file1.txt )

#init file size array. Each time a file will be added to an output file, its size will be added here. 
# If its size doesn't fit in an existing file, it will be added to a new file. New file will be added to foutputs_array,...
# If it doesn't fit anywhere, it will go to leftover.

fsize_array=( "0" "0" )

#5GB limit

FLIMIT=5242880

FLAG=0
i=1
array_index=1

fitIn(){

local file_size=$1
local total_size=$2
#echo "summing.." >&2
sum=$(expr $file_size + $total_size)
#echo "sum=" "$sum" >&2
if [[ "$sum" -le "$FLIMIT" ]];then
 echo 0
else
 echo 1
fi
}


while read fsize fname

do
# echo "array_index=" $array_index ${fsize_array[@]} "fsize"$fsize ${fsize_array[$array_index]} 
 check_size=`fitIn $fsize ${fsize_array[$array_index]}`
# echo "check_size" $check_size
 if [ "$fsize" -le "$FLIMIT" -a "$check_size" -eq "0" ];then
 #  echo "In limit"
   FLAG=0  
 elif [ $fsize -le $FLIMIT ];then
 #  echo "In max limit"
   FLAG=0
   while [ $check_size -eq "1" ]
    do
#     echo $array_index $i
     (( array_index++ )) 
     (( i++ )) 
     if [ -z ${fsize_array[$array_index]} ];then 
      fsize_array[$array_index]=0
     fi
     check_size=`fitIn $fsize ${fsize_array[$array_index]}`
    done
#    echo "new position" $array_index
    foutputs_array[$array_index]="$outputs_dir"/file${i}.txt
 else
  echo "$fsize $fname doesn't fit anywhere!"
  FLAG=1
  array_index=0 
 fi 

 if [ $FLAG -eq 0 ];then
  (( fsize_array[$array_index]+=$fsize ))
 fi
 echo "$fsize" "$fname" >> "${foutputs_array[$array_index]}"
 array_index=1
 i=1  
done <<< "$SRC"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your list is sorted by size, or could easily be sorted by size, so if you wanted to optimise this a bit using [*First Fit Decreasing* strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Analysis_of_approximate_algorithms), you could use the following Awk script (lovely, and understandable) with `tac` to read the input file from the bottom (only required because it's sorted by file size in ascending order):

```
BEGIN {
    Max_bin_size = 5 * 2^30;    # 5GB
    File_counter = Bin_counter = 0;
    split("", Bins);
    split("", Bin_space_avail);
    # Allocate space for first bin
    Bin_space_avail[Bin_counter] = Max_bin_size;
}

{
    File_size = $1;
    File_name = $2;
    Bin_to_use = Bin_counter + 1; # Assume we need a new bin
    for (i = 0; i <= Bin_counter; i++) {
        # Too big for any bin
        if (File_size > Max_bin_size) { 
            printf("File too big (%d): %s\n", File_size, File_name) > "/dev/stderr";
            next;
        }
        # Found some space!
        if (File_size <= Bin_space_avail[i]) {
            Bin_to_use = i;      
            break;        
        }
    }
    # Exhausted search for space, so add space to new bin
    if (Bin_to_use > Bin_counter) {
        Bin_space_avail[++Bin_counter] = Max_bin_size;
    }
    Bins[Bin_to_use] = Bins[Bin_to_use] "\n\t" $0;
    Bin_space_avail[Bin_to_use] -= File_size;
}

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"; # Requires gawk >= 4.0
    for (i in Bins) {
        printf("file%d:%s\n", i, Bins[i]);
    }
}
```

then just combine it with `tac` in `bash`:

```bsh
$ tac unix_StackExchange_question.txt | awk -f script_above.awk
```

For example, setting `Max_bin_size = 5 * 2^20` (5 MB), you can see some extra space being consumed by smaller files which are not in sequential order:

```
file0:
        1757076 499.txt
        1488592 498.txt
        1204392 497.txt
        787724  254.txt
file1:  
        1138380 496.txt
        1138380 495.txt
        1138120 494.txt
        1138120 493.txt
        689784  111.txt
file2:  
        1137784 492.txt
        1137784 491.txt
        1120988 490.txt
        1116348 489.txt
        718600  234.txt
```

The trade-off is processing time, though, somewhere between *O(N)* and *O(N<sup>2</sup>)* depending on the distribution of items, item sizes, and bin size. It's reasonably fast for your sample:

```bsh
$ time tac unix_StackExchange_question.txt | awk -f script_above.awk > /dev/null

real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.028s
sys     0m0.004s
```